# What is SELECT NULL in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

While reading SQL Server 2012 doc., I came across the following example:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012 ;
GO
SELECT DepartmentID, Name 
FROM HumanResources.Department 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL)
ORDER BY Name ASC ;
```

I haven't seen `SELECT NULL` before. What is it, and how it works in given example ? (Obviously, `SELECT NULL` returns `NULL`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SELECT NULL` returns a single row, with a single column, containing `NULL`

You can verify this by running `SELECT NULL` in SSMS.

The purpose of it in the query you posted is to illustrate that `EXISTS` doesn't care about the content of its subquery, only that **something** is returned, in this case a row with `NULL`

This is in contrast to something like `COUNT` which **does not** consider `NULL` in it's aggregations

Consider this:

```
SELECT 
    1
WHERE
    EXISTS(SELECT NULL)
-- Returns 1
```

versus this:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(r.c)
FROM
    (SELECT CAST(NULL AS int) AS c) AS r
-- Returns 0
```

Comment: As a personal comment, I think `select NULL` in this context is confusing.  Much better to use `select 1` or `select 'x'` or anything else.

Comment: AH, I didn't understood the purpose of `EXISTS` statement. Got it now.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the entire premise of the `EXISTS` clause in this example is silly. `NULL` and 1 are both constants.... there should be no functional difference. In this contrived situation I would probably prefer `NULL` because at least that demonstrates that you *don't care* what it is.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT NULL` is used along with `WHERE EXISTS` to show the exist status but not data (When you don't need it)

For example you can have:

```
Select something 
From a b
Where Exists (SELECT NULL 
              From C item
              on item.cID = b.cID)
```